# Check for a value from one dataframe exists in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes.

```
df1

id    marks
1      100
2      200
3      300


df2

name    score  flag
'abc'    100    T
'zxc'    300    F
```

What I am looking for is the from the first row of my df1,
check the corresponding column `score` in my df2 , and get the Flag of that.

i.e

```
row = df1.iloc[0]
marks = row['marks']
```

find the corresponding value in marks from df2, and give what Flag it has.

i.e 
`for marks 100 ====corresponds to score 100 and flag = T`

I don't want to use pandas `merge`, as I only want to look for my first row. using `iloc[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First Row

**Option 1**

You can use `df.isin`:

```
first_flag = df2[df2.score.isin([df1.marks[0]])].flag
print(first_flag)
0    T
```

To get the values, use `.values.tolist()`:

```
print(first_flag.values.tolist())
['T']
```

To get a single the value as a single item, use `.item`:

```
print(first_flag.item())
'T'
```

---

**Option 2**

Using `df.eval`:

```
score = df1.marks[0]
first_flag = df2[df2.eval('score == {}'.format(score))].flag
print(first_flag)
0    T
```

---

**Option 3**

Using `df.eq`

```
score = df1.marks[0]
first_flag = df2[df2.score.eq(score)].flag
print(first_flag) 
0    T
```

---

## All Rows

Use `df.merge`.

```
flags = df1.merge(df2, left_on='marks', right_on='score').flag
print(flags)
0    T
1    F
Name: flag, dtype: object
```

If you want to retrieve `NaN` for rows where no flag exists, you can do a `left` join:

```
flags = df1.merge(df2, left_on='marks', right_on='score', how='left').flag
print(flags)
0      T
1    NaN
2      F
```

Comment: Can't it be done without using merge!
Merge gives me all the rows, i want it only for first row, using iloc[0]

Comment: @SRingne Added more options. You have a lot of options to choose from :p

Comment: @COLDSPEED , ok, i've located that flag.
2nd step:- can i change that particular flag from `T` to 'F' ? as a next line of code?

Comment: @SRingne In every case, you will need to change `df2[...].flag` to `df2.loc[..., 'flag'] = 'F'` But the short answer is: yes. You need the `loc` indexer.

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
In [437]: df2[df2.score.eq(df1.iloc[0].marks)]   # or  df1.marks[0]
Out[437]:
    name  score flag
0  'abc'    100    T

In [438]: df2[df2.score.eq(df1.iloc[0].marks)].flag
Out[438]:
0    T
Name: flag, dtype: object
```

Or, use

```
In [442]: df2[df2.score == df1.marks.iloc[0]].flag
Out[442]:
0    T
Name: flag, dtype: object
```

Or, use query

```
In [441]: df2.query('score == @df1.marks[0]').flag
Out[441]:
0    T
Name: flag, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
a = df2.loc[df2['score'].eq(df1['marks'].iat[0]), 'flag']
print (a)
0    T
Name: flag, dtype: object
```

---

```
a = df2.loc[df2['score'] == df1['marks'].iat[0], 'flag']
print (a)
0    T
Name: flag, dtype: object
```

For scalar output:

```
b = 'no match' if a.empty else a.item()
print (b)
T
```